# Correctly present new Scene?

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm currently trying to use the following to transition from one scene to another and it keeps compiling to an error.

```
-(void)presentGameScene{
      SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition doorwayWithDuration:1.0];
      [self.view presentScene:gameScene transition:transition];
 }
```

I copied this from a tutorial website hoping to figure it out later, but I think
I'm missing something.

Comment: what error do you get? (obvious here but if you don't spare us helpful details like that you're more likely to get an answer)

Comment: Sorry.. it said "Use of undeclared identifier 'gameScene'.. I hadn't declared it within the method was my problem ._. got it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies in that you are calling "gameScene" without specifying what it is within the bounds of the method; perhaps you allocated and initialized it outside of this method you declared?

Usually a scene transition should look like this:

```
-(void)presentGameScene{
 YourSceneClassName *gameScene = [[YourSceneClassName alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
 SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition doorwayWithDuration:1.0];
 [self.view presentScene:gameScene transition:transition];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

where init `gameScene`?

try:

```
  -(void)presentGameScene {

    GameScene *gameScene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition doorwayWithDuration:1.0];
    [self.view presentScene:gameScene transition:transition];
  }
```

GameScene is your `SKScene` that you have imported in this view